# preg_match replace ALL condition with ANY

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match

Seems like

```
preg_match('/^[\p{Cyrillic}]+$/', $str)
```

returns 0 or 1 based on if `$str` contains **ALL** Cyrillic letters.

I need 0 or 1 based on if `$str` contains **ANY** Cyrillic letters.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
$ret = preg_match('/\p{Cyrillic}/u', $str);
```

to figure if input string contains any `Cyrillic` character or not. `/u` flag is required to handle unicode string inputs.

Alternatively use [`mb_ereg` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ereg.php) for multibyte regex match like this:

```
$str = 'БДКЯ'; // string with Cyrillic characters only

// check with Cyrillic string only
var_dump( mb_ereg('\p{Cyrillic}', $str) ); // int(1)

// check with mix of Cyrillic and ASCII characters
var_dump( mb_ereg('\p{Cyrillic}', $str . 'abc') ); // int(1)

// check with ASCII characters only
var_dump( mb_ereg('\p{Cyrillic}', 'abc') ); // bool(false)
```

Answer (score 1):

The anchors `^` and `$` force the `{Cyrillic}` character match from the beginning to the end of the string, so remove them.  Also, the character class `[]` and `+` are not needed because you are looking for any match:

```
 /\p{Cyrillic}/
```